# Finding the characteristic polynomial of $A^2$ given the characteristic polynomial of $A$

Tags: linear-algebra, matrices

The characteristic polynomial of $A$ is $\lambda^2+4\lambda-5$.
To find the characteristic polynomial of the matrix $A^2$ would I just compute $$(\lambda^2+4\lambda-5)^2 ?$$

Comment: try an eigen-decomposition

Answer (score 7):

No, $A^2$ is a $2 \times 2$ matrix, so its characteristic polynomial must again have degree $2$.

**Hint** Factoring the characteristic polynomial $\chi_A$ of $A$ gives
$$\chi_A(\lambda) = \lambda^2 + 4 \lambda - 5 = (\lambda + 5)(\lambda - 1).$$
What are the eigenvalues of $A$? Then, what are the eigenvalues of $A^2$? Finally, what is the characteristic polynomial of $A^2$?

Comment: so the eigenvalues of A^2 would be 25 and 1? so the characteristic polynomial of A^2 would be (λ-25)(λ-1)?

Comment: Yes, you've got it!

Comment: Thank you for the help! Have a nice night! :)

Comment: You're welcome, I'm glad you found it helpful! (And it's still day in my time zone. :) )